# Python MainWindow class can't find attribute

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am building a GUI application and I've been trying to debug the code and test it but it keeps throwing me this error saying. I added a button function to the MainWindow class which is 'self.AddtoCart.clicked.connect(self.addCart)' but now it won't open.

'MainWindow' Object has no attribute 'addCart'.

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent=parent)
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.Addtocart.clicked.connect(self.addCart)



def addcart(self):
    style = self.comboBox_6.currentText()
    name = self.lineEdit_10.text()
    color = self.lineEdit_11.text()
    size = self.comboBox_7.currentText()
    text = "style: {style}, name: {name}, color: {color}, size: {size}".format(style=style, name=name, color=color, size=size)
    self.plainTextEdit.appendPlainText(text)
```

Comment: Please indent your code, indentation is important in python.

Answer (score -1):

In your code, addcart() is not in the scope of MainWindow, since it is at the same indentation level. Indent the functions with a tab and addCart() will become an attribute of the class.

Comment: Moreover the method is called addcart, but the button is connected to addCart. Python is case sensitive.